# window.print() stopped working in Chrome. How do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, printing

I have a React app, which includes several Print buttons, who call window.print(), to print the page:

```
onPrint = () => {
  window.print();
}
```

A couple of days ago, all of my print buttons abruptly stopped working. I have checked that the windows.print function is present and is being called, but absolutely nothing happens. The print dialog does not appear. There is no message in the console or anywhere else.

Logging the print function confirms that it is the native function and has not been overridden.

CTRL-P works fine, but not window.print().

The print buttons work fine in the Edge browser, and also, bizarrely, from an incognito window in Chrome. The problem only happens when my app is open in a normal Chrome tab.

I know it's not just something with my setup since I am now getting angry phone calls from clients, complaining that their print buttons are no longer working.

I am completely at a loss here. Has anyone else experienced similar problems with the print function in Chrome?

Edit: Oh, and the print button also works if I run my app locally on localhost:.... It only stops working when the app is deployed to the server and accessed through my domain (https://example.com). This just keeps getting weirder. Maybe the SSL cert is involved, somehow?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you experiencing the problem on?

Comment: 77.0.3865.90. I just updated, to make sure I wasn't missing a fix.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013635#c17

This bug has been confirmed by the Chromium bug team and will be fixed in Chrome version 80.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It should only affect React in development mode, not the production build.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=956832

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013635

No, it was this bug, like I wrote in my own answer. It happened in the production build.